# How to prove property of greatest integer function:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> How can we prove that
>   $$\lfloor x + y \rfloor = \lfloor y + x -  \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor$$
>   for all real $x$, where $ \lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes greatest integer less than or equal to $x$?

I was able to prove that $\lfloor x + y \rfloor =  \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor $ or $\lfloor x + y \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + 1$ by using the property that $\lfloor x \rfloor = m$ means $m \le x \lt m + 1$ but cannot prove above one by any means. I have tried a lot, can any one please help and please give a simple proof?

Comment: I know this page, actually I used this site to prove the formula in below mentioned way.

Comment: This is not correct as written.  For example, if $x = y = 1$, then $[x+y] = 2$ but $[y+x-[x]] = 1$.

Comment: You also have to add [x] = 1. Hence it becomes 2.

Comment: Sorry I skipped it. I have edited the question.

Comment: Let [x] be floor and {x} = x - [x] be fractional part and note 0<= {x} < 1. So 0 < = {y} + {x} < 2.  So we have two cases i) 0 <= {y} + {x} < 1$ and ii)1 <= {y} + {x} < 2.  Case i)[y + x] = [[y] + [x] + {x} + {y}] = [[y] + [x]].  As [y] and [x] are integers [[y] + [x]] = [y] + [x].  A {x}+{y} < 1, [y] = [[y] + {x} + {y}] = [y + x - [x]] and we are done.  Case ii) [y + x] = [[y] + [x] + {x} + {y}] = [[y] + [x]] + 1 = [y] + [x] + 1 = [y + 1] + [x]=[[y] + {x} + {y}] + [x] = [y + x - [x]] + [x] and we are done.

Comment: It is simply $\ \lfloor z - n \rfloor = \lfloor z\rfloor -n\ $ for $\,z=x\!+\!y,\ n = \lfloor x\rfloor\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is an integer and $t$ any real number, then it is straightforward to show that$\lfloor t + n \rfloor = \lfloor t \rfloor + n.$
Therefore, since $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer,
\begin{align*}
\quad &\lfloor y + x -  \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor \\
= &\lfloor y + x \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor \\
= &\lfloor x + y \rfloor.
\end{align*}

Comment: That was simple and helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you introduced the notation {$x$} = $x - [x]$ and note $0 \le \{x\} < 1$ this becomes easy.

$0 \le \{x\} + \{y\} < 2$.

Case 1:  $0 \le \{x\} + \{y\} < 1$.

Note for integers $n, m$ and $0 \le r < 1$ that: $[n + m + r] = n+m$ and $[n + m] = n + m$.  As $[x]$ and $[y]$ are integers:

Then $[x + y] = [[x]+ [y] + \{x\} + \{y\}] = [[x] + [y]] = [x] + [y]$.

Furthermore $[y] = [[y] + \{y\} + \{x\}]= [y + x - [x]]$ so $[x + y]=[y + x - [x]] + [x]$.

Case 2:  $1 \le \{x\} + \{y\} < 2$

Then $[x + y] = [[x]+ [y] + \{x\} + \{y\}] = [[x] + [y]] + 1 = [x] + [y]+ 1$

And note $[y + x - [x]] = [y + \{x\}] = [[y] + \{y\} + \{x\}] = [[y] + 1] = [y]+1$.

So $[x +y] = [x]+[y] + 1 = [x] + [y + x - [x]]$.